# use less in node.js--- throw error : Cannot read property 'contents' of undefined at Object.Parser.parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, less

There is an error when I use less in node. I changed file or directory name for some attempt, but it throw the error:

```
cannot read property "contents" of undefined
```

I don't know where I'm wrong.

My directory is as follows:

```
node-file c:\ndexp\appless.js  
less-parser-file  C:\ndexp\node_modules\less\lib\less\parser
less code-file C:\ndexp\lss\exp.less
```

Part codes in *appless.js* is as follows:

```
enter code here

var less=require("less");
 var options={
    paths:[__dirname,"./lss"],
    outputDir:__dirname+"./lss",
    optimization:1,
    filename:"exp.less",
    compress:true,
    yuicompress:true
}
var parser=new less.Parser(options);


parser.parse('.class{width:1+1}', function (e, tree) {
    tree.toCSS({ compress: true }); 
});
```

Comment: First of all you do not pass any options to the parser since your `options` var is defined *after* parser. Next `filename` option should set full path to the existing file (in your snippet Less won't be able to find `C:\ndexp\lss\exp.less`). And finally you should not set `filename` if the source string is not the contents of that file (beside resolving imports and urls when nesecary, Less will use that file contents for error reporting and there you'll just got wrong message).

Comment: (Well, there're actually more not so major errors in your code, though I won't bother you with those since your code apparently tries to use some outdated version of Less (that I simply don't have to try to run your snippet and test every line of it)).

Comment: yes,i copy wrong code,and i change it now.

Comment: So as I mentioned the probem is in `filename:"exp.less"` - it should be resolvable path to the file not just file name (note that the `paths` option applies to imports only and does not specify "input dir", hence Less tries to read `exp.less` in the current directory and since it does not exists you get that `undefined` error (since you do that programmatically, the compiler trusts to you and does not perform any additional file tests / error handling).

Comment: sorry,i do not understand,how to change de code.  Delete filename  is ok? i had done it but it is also wrong